# Sails.js file upload returns empty files array when large file is uploaded in multi-upload form

Tags: file-upload, sails.js, skipper

I have multipart form in my Sails.js project which submits 2 different files (first **audio** then **image**) along with some text params. In most cases with rather small files, everything works fine. But when I tried a bigger audio file (*33MB*) I got empty files array for my image field in the receiver.
Here is some code.

The Controller:

```
var uploadParamNames = ['audio', 'image'];

async.map(uploadParamNames, 
    function (file, cb) {

       sails.log(req.file(file)._files)
       req.file(file).upload(
       {
           adapter:     require('skipper-gridfs'),
           uri:         sails.config.connections.mongoConnection.url + '.' + file           
       }, 
       function (err, files) {
           // save the file, and then:
           return cb(err, files);
    });

}, function doneUploading(err, files) {
...
});
```

Basicaly here I get the following logs for audio and image:

```
[ { stream: [Object], status: 'bufferingOrWriting' } ]
[]
```

I tried a debug and found that in case of image field it never reached the line where the file is actually written in `prototype.onFile.js` line `up.writeFile(part);`.

Also the debug log prints the following:

```
Parser: Read a chunk of textparam through field `_csrf`
Parser: Read a chunk of textparam through field `ss-name`
Parser: Read a chunk of textparam through field `ss-desc`
Parser: Read a chunk of textparam through field `ss-category`
Parser: Read a chunk of textparam through field `ss-language`
Parser: Read a chunk of textparam through field `ss-place`
Parser: Read a chunk of textparam through field `ss-place-lat`
Parser: Read a chunk of textparam through field `ss-place-lon`
Acquiring new Upstream for field `audio`
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:52:54 GMT skipper Set up "maxTimeToWaitForFirstFile" timer for 10000ms
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:52:58 GMT skipper passed control to app because first file was received
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:52:58 GMT skipper waiting for any text params
Upstream: Pumping incoming file through field `audio`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `_csrf`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `ss-name`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `ss-desc`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `ss-category`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `ss-language`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `ss-tags`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `ss-place`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `ss-place-lat`
Parser: Done reading textparam through field `ss-place-lon`
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:53:11 GMT skipper Something is trying to read from Upstream `audio`...
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:53:11 GMT skipper Passing control to app...
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:53:16 GMT skipper maxTimeToWaitForFirstFile timer fired- as of now there are 1 file uploads pending (so it's fine)
debug: [ { stream: [Object], status: 'bufferingOrWriting' } ]
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:53:41 GMT skipper .upload() called on upstream
Acquiring new Upstream for field `image`
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:53:46 GMT skipper Set up "maxTimeToWaitForFirstFile" timer for 10000ms
debug: []
```

Not sure why, but it seems the control is already passed to the app before image file is written. Again this only happens with a larger audio file. Is there a way to fix this?

**EDIT:**
More debugging showed that the `receivedFirstFileOfRequest` listener is called before image file is written. Which is logical, because it actually listens for first file upload, but what to do with next files?

**EDIT:**
Ah... the file doesn't need to bee very large at all. A 29KB file passes and a 320KB does not...

Comment: I have a somewhat similar problem. Two small params (json) and then a large file. If I do it in localhost, works ok, if I simulate (throttling) bad internet connection on Chrome, then I got undefiend in both jsons, though the image is save to the disk.

Comment: ArVan, did you ever manage to get this working? I've run into a very similar problem where my text parameters go missing if I'm sending a couple of hundred KB file, but <100KB seems to work fine (though even this size varies for when it works... I've had 18KB files cause the text parameters to be lost sometimes).